# Get Google Client API access token using CURL

Tags: php, curl, access-token, google-api-client

I have been trying for the last couple of days trying to get an access token and refresh token using Google Oauth2 but not getting anywhere.

The documentation is rubbish and I can't find any examples that work.

I have just started to use CURL trying to get the access code and refresh token but I keep getting errors with the response.

I have tried using this

```
// init the resource
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-length: 0'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    'code=' . urlencode('AUTHORISATION_CODE') . '&' .
    'client_id=' . urlencode('MY_CLINET_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com') . '&' .
    'client_secret=' . urlencode('MY_CLIENT_SECRET') . '&' .
    'redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/' . '&' .
    'grant_type=authorization_code'
); 

// execute
$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;

// free
curl_close($ch);
```

but i just get this response

```
{ 
   "error" : "invalid_request", 
   "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

and I've tried running CURL from the command line

```
curl --data "code=AUTHORISATION_CODE&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/&grant_type=authorization_code" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

but i just get a different response

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_client",
  "error_description" : "The OAuth client was not found."
}
```

Why is it so difficult just to get an access token?

**UPDATE**

I don't know what's happening but I don't receive that error anymore and I get an access token but not a refresh token

I've looked at this post [Not receiving Google OAuth refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/google-oauth-refresh-token-is-not-being-received) and I've revoked access to my app to regenerate the refresh token  but using this code displays an error about an invalid code

Comment: Just an idea, but omit the last `/` from the `redirect_uri`. Or escape that somehow.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference

Comment: What you said. I remove the trailing slash from the redirect_url and also edited the redirect_url to match in the console

Comment: Hmm, try swapping `redirect_uri` and `grant_type`.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I just took out the redirect_url and it didn't even complain about that, it just said grant_type missing

Comment: Wow, good you solved it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now fixed the problem using Curl.  Didn't seem any reason why the above didn't work as just keeping trying, it worked eventually after revoking access to app, authing the app, getting the code and using the code in the Curl request.

This solved my previous question [YouTube API v3 keeps asking for authorisation every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786842/youtube-api-v3-keeps-asking-for-authorisation-every-time)